# Find specific key in a given object in JS

Tags: javascript, json

Find specific key in a given object including nested objects and nested arrays of objects. what could be best solution or technic in javascript?

Given key: `reference`
Given Object:

```json
{
  "reference": "Patient/1",
  "subjectOrAnyKey": {
    "reference": "Patient/2"
  },
  "containedOrAnyKey": [
    {
      "reference": "Practitioner/4"
    },
    {
      "subjectOrAnyKey": {
        "reference": "Patient/11"
      },
      "requesterOrAnyKey": {
        "reference": "Practitioner/3"
      },
      "performerOrAnyKey": [
        {
          "reference": "Practitioner/4"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

PS: Solved using the following:

```js
    function findAllValues(obj, key){
        for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(obj)){
            if (k === key) {
                console.log(v)
            } else if (v.constructor === Array && !v.length === false){
                for (let entry of v){
                    findAllValues(entry, key)
                }
            } else if (v.constructor === Object && !Object.keys(v).length === false) {
                findAllValues(v, key)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what have you tried yet? please add.

Comment: make an array of object keys using Object.keys() and iterate using foreach() loop and find the reference is equal to given key

Comment: It may sound strange, but in this case I'd probably go back to a string and extract the relevant value with some regex magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion comes in handy in these types of objects, where you can't determine how nested they can be

please find the below snippet

a function that loops through every key inside an object, if the key matches and it's type is not an object, it prints its value. if it's an object, it calls the method itself with the nested object.

```
function findAllKeys(obj, key){
    for(let prop in obj){
        if(typeof obj[prop] !== 'object' && prop === key)
            console.log(obj[prop]);
        else if(typeof obj[prop] === 'object')
            findAllKeys(obj[prop],key)
    }
}
```